# Google navigation | Custom AppBar with nav_graph

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, navigation, android-navigation-view

Хочу сделать кастомный `AppBar` на каждый фрагмент свой заголовок с кнопками и т.д. Для приложения установил `NoActionBar`. Добавил `FragmentContainerView` размером `?attr/actionBarSize` и новым `nav_graph_appbar` во фрагмент контейнер и добавил два фрагмента (класс+xml) для изменения. В обычной ситуации для перемещения использую `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action)`. Как при переходе на фрагмент вызывать смену фрагмента `AppBar` совместно с `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action)`? Т.е. при переходе на фрагмент через, например, кнопку в дополнение к основному фрагменту изменялся `AppBar` фрагмент.

```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container_view"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:text="@string/main_fragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_app_bar" />
```

Тут ещё `action` добавляются.

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/feedAppBarFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ui.feed.FeedAppBarFragment"
        android:label="FeedAppBarFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feed_app_bar"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailsAppBarFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ui.feed_details.DetailsAppBarFragment"
        android:label="DetailsAppBarFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_details_app_bar"/>
```

```
view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.feedItemView).setOnClickListener {         
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_feedFragment_to_detailFragment2)
}
```